# How to shift contents of a string vector up after calling erase C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to implement an undo function for inserting a new line for a simple text editor program. 
When I call a new line, I increment the row of a vector of strings, and insert an empty string into it. This pushes everything below the new row down by one. It looks something like this (where | is the cursor):

```
Before

1: Hello
2: |World

After inserting a new line between hello and world

1: Hello
2: 
3: |World
```

When I call my undo function I want it to delete the line (the empty one in this case), and then push every row up by one. I know `insert()` handles shifting elements, but is there some sort of equivalent for `erase()`? Here is my code for `insertNewLine()`

```
void Editor::insertNewLine()
{
    std::string currLine = lines[row];
    size_t tempSize = currLine.size();
    int lengthOffset = getSubstringOffset(tempSize, column);
    std::string cutTemp = currLine.substr(column, lengthOffset);
    // Insert a new line
    lines[row].erase(column);
    // after incrementing, row and amount of lines, initialize the new row
    numberOfLines++;
    lines.insert(lines.begin() + row, ""); // initialize and shift other rows
    row++;
    column = 1;
    lines[row] += cutTemp; // insert substring into new line
}
```

My attempt at undoing this works if I don't have any rows underneath the thing I'm about to undo.
Here is my current code for undo:

```
void Editor::undoNewLine()
{
    size_t updateCol = lines[row - 1].size(); // holds size of our old string
    lines[row - 1] += lines[row];
    lines[row].erase(column);
    row--;
    numberOfLines--;
    column = updateCol; // update to point back to where we were
}
```

And here is what it looks like when I erase something that has rows underneath it:

```
Before (we insert new lines, and end up creating a new line after row 1, which we want to undo)

1. Hello
2. |
3. asdf
4. rld

After user hits undo key

1. |Hello
2. 
3. asdf
```

Here is what it should look like though:

```
Before

1. Hello
2. |
3. asdf
4. rld

After

1. |Hello
2. asdf
3. rld
```

So how can I erase an element and have it shift everything up one line like `insert()` does?

Comment: What does `lines[row].erase(column)` do? Where does the `column` variable come from?

Comment: `vector::erase` *does* shift the following elements down to fill the hole. If it doesn't *appear* to then your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @MarceloCantos column is just the cursors current position. So in this case, it is the index of the string we are currently on

Comment: Shouldn't you be erasing a *row* and not a *column*?

Comment: @Alex: OK, so why are you calling it in `insertNewLine()`? And why is it the only thing you are calling in `undoNewLine()`?

Comment: @MarceloCantos When inserting a new line when the cursor is at a specific position, I have to move every character past the column down to the new line. So, after I store the substring from column -> end, I erase from column -> end (in insertNewLine())

Comment: @Praetorian not sure why I thought not erasing the row, but just each element in the column would work. doing lines.erase(row) worked.. thank you

Comment: @Alex: Ah. In your question, you state that you insert an empty line, not the tail end of the current line. Anyway, single-parameter erase doesn't erase a range. It erases a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the row instead of deleting in the string:

```
void Editor::undoNewLine()
{
    size_t updateCol = lines[row - 1].size(); // holds size of our old string
    lines[row - 1] += lines[row];
    lines.erase(lines.begin() + row);
    row--;
    numberOfLines--;
    column = updateCol; // update to point back to where we were
}
```

Third line was `lines[row].erase(column);` who -- from what I understand -- erase in your string.

BTW you should avoid having `numberOfLines` because it needs to reflect exactly `lines.size()` and here the bug would have been obvious, I think, if you had use `lines.size()`, which was still 4.